# I applied GitHub Theme VScode, but the text color is not perfectly the same

Tags: visual-studio-code

I applied the extension [GitHub](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.github-vscode-theme) Theme, but the text color is not the same.

**GitHub**
[image]

**VScode**
[image]

I've tried this and can't tell the difference.

```
  "workbench.colorTheme": "GitHub Dark Dimmed",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "[GitHub Dark Dimmed]": {
            "textBlockQuote.background": "#ee3355ff",
            "textBlockQuote.border": "#ee3355ff",
            "textCodeBlock.background": "#ee3355ff",
            "textLink.activeForeground": "#ee3355ff",
            "textLink.foreground": "#ee3355ff",
            "textPreformat.foreground": "#ee3355ff",
            "textSeparator.foreground": "#ee3355ff",
        },
    }
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve that?

Comment: I guess it has something to do with Python extension or Pylance. Somebody changes the colors because this problem is not limited to github-theme. I faced this issue with other themes as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I still haven't solved the problem, I'm relieved to hear that it wasn't just me after all.